# Does dynamic dispatch come into play when I have a concrete type?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dispatch

Lets say I have a class `Interface` which provides pure virtual functions.
Now lets say I have two classes `Concrete1` and `Concrete2`.

I instantiate them like this:

```
Interface* impl = createConcrete1orConcrete2(); // randomly select Concrete1 or Concrete2
Concrete1* concrete = new Concrete1();
impl->foo();
concrete->foo();
```

Will `concrete` make use of dynamic dispatch?

Comment: I guess it has to. What if `concrete` pointed to an object of a class derived from `Concrete1`? The question is whether a compiler may under optimization bypass dynamic dispatch when it can derive the dynamic type during compilation.

Comment: Compiler might devirtualize (as-if rule). if class or method is marked as `final`, it might help.

Comment: Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1zE9677Kn. Note that in `f1`, `D::f()` is called directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler has to do the dynamic dispatch, but following the as-if rule, it might devirtualize the call if it know the final dynamic type as optimization.

Here indeed, with `new Concrete1();`, dynamic type is known.

But for `Concrete* ConcreteFactoryCreate()`, it wouldn't (`Concrete` might still have derived classes) unless the help of `final` on the class or on the method.